Django reversed for loop slice
I am currently trying to reverse a slice of a list going from 0 to 11
class Game(models.Model):
    board = models.JSONField(default=list)

game = Game(board=[4] * 12, scores=[0, 0], current_player=0, game_over=False)

Here is part of index.html
<div>
    {% for i in game.board|slice:"6:12" reversed%}
        <a href="{% url 'make_move' forloop.counter0 %}" > {{ i }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

Here is what I have in views.py
def make_move(request, pit):

    print(f"Make move called. Pit: {pit}")

pit will always print from 0 to 5, when I expect it to print 11, 10, 9, etc
It feels that slice and reversed have no effect on i in this case

So what is game.board?

class Game(models.Model):
board = models.JSONField(default=list)

List contains ints
Updated the post

So how does the previous row looks like? 0 to 5, or 5 to 0?

In that case 0 to 5

The loop counter always starts from 0 and goes to n, the number of elements. You here slice the list before passing it to the loop, so the loop even does not know it enumerates over a bigger list.
I would actually advise to do the processing in the view not the template. It is not good practice to write business logic in the template. Normally that belongs in the model or in the view. Django's template language is deliberately restricted to prevent people from writing such logic in the template.
In the view we thus can work with:
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def my_view(request, gid):
    game = get_object_or_404(Game, pk=gid)
    idxs = [range(6), range(11, 5, -1)]
    game_board = [
        [(i, game.board[i]) for i in row]
        for row in idxs
    ]
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'game': game, 'game_board': game_board})
and in the template:
{% for row in game_board %}
<div>
    {% for idx, j in row %}
        <a href="{% url 'make_move' idx %}" > {{ j }} </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
